# How to run a method above before all junit test cases in maven test project

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have a maven test project, and I run the test cases via maven command.

Now there is some requirement that I want to run a single method before any of the test case is executed for that project.
so it will be like at first my method is run, and then the test case execution starts.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Why would you do that? I cannot imagin a reason that *all* unittest in a project need the same prequequest to setup other than a misconception about what unitests are...

Comment: I agree with Timothy. If that is your requirement; it sounds like a **design problem** you should somehow get rid of.

Comment: What ever the reason could be...

I think the @BeforeClass would work well if you check in that method if whatever you want to run was already run or not.

Comment: I agree with both Timothy and GhostCar. In Unit testing definition, "Ideally, each test case is independent from the others" (source : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)

Comment: You can make an abstract superclass for all your tests and use @BeforeClass to execute the setup for your test suite

Comment: I would use [JUnit Rules](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Rules) for this instead of a superclass. Classes should rather be used for specialization, where as rules allow for non hierarchical setup of such *before* features. Downside: do we really want to put that everywhere?

Comment: I would create some test data in my application I am testing, then, I would run my test cases against that test data. Then I would delete that test data. How can I achieve that? @GhostCat

Comment: My all test classes already have superclass. Cant add another superclass and i dont want to write interface and then implement that method in the class. @NickVanderhoven

Comment: Problem is: it is really not clear what you are asking for. I recommend looking into http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ... and probably try to completely rework this question; or better: ask a new one with more precise content. We cant help with such vague input. And if you wrote all your testclasses to have a common superclass, that alone sounds like ... another design problem.